# Remove duplicated rows including the first row tied in multiple columns

Tags: excel

I want to remove *all* of the duplicate rows in each columns, including the first duplicated row, leaving only rows that did not have any duplicates at all, **but the duplicate rows must have match in both columns**. Is that possible somehow in table with thousands of rows?

```
A           B
ID201       225 (leave this)
ID201       233 (leave this)
ID202       555 (delete this)
ID202       555 (delete this)
etc
```

Comment: Select column A and B, Click Data > Remove Duplicates

Comment: But this function will leave the first one row, isnt it?.

Comment: That function will delete leave only one data of each kind and delete everything. Makes the all data unique.

Comment: Now I get your question..=P You need Macro to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a macro, there is a slow way and a fast way to do this.  If you know that every item in the first column will be of the form "ID somenumber", then we can use the fast method.  If not, the slow method (checking each row against every other row in sequence) must be employed.  I've included the code for the fast method below

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim IDVals As Object, RowsToDelete As String, ItemsToDelete As String
Set IDVals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim CheckCell As Range
For Each CheckCell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
    If Not IDVals.Exists(CheckCell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(CheckCell) Then
        IDVals.Add (CheckCell.Value), CheckCell.Address
    Else
        If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).Offset(0, 1).Value = CheckCell.Value Then
            RowsToDelete = RowsToDelete & CheckCell.Row & ","
            ItemsToDelete = ItemsToDelete & CheckCell.Value & ","
        End If
    End If
Next CheckCell

RowsToDelete = Left(RowsToDelete, Len(RowsToDelete) - 1) 'Removing last comma
Dim ParsedText() As String, Count As Integer, DeleteRange As Range
Elements = Len(RowsToDelete) - Len(Replace(RowsToDelete, ",", "")) 'Array of the length of elements
ReDim ParsedText(Elements)
ParsedText = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",")
DeleteRange = Range(Cells(Val(ParsedText(0)), 1).Address).EntireRow

For Count = 1 To Elements

    DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, Range(Cells(Val(ParsedText(Count)), 1).Address).EntireRow)

Next Count

DeleteRange.Delete

Dim IdValkey As String

'eliminating first instance of repeated value
For Each IdValkey In Split(Left(ItemsToDelete, Len(ItemsToDelete) - 1), ",")
    For Count = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)) To 1
        If Cells(Count, 1).Value = IdValkey Then
            Range(Cells(Count, 1).Address).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Count
Next IdValkey
End Sub
```

Comment: Just realized you wanted both columns to match.  will adjust the code for that quickly now

Comment: Code is now corrected to function as desired.  The trick (that makes the code much faster) is using the dictionary object, though this relies on the fact that the string format of the items in the first column are identical (ones that are intended to be the same but are not identical will be passed over without more clever string parsing that I didn't bother to include)

Comment: I actually used Kutools extension for Excel, because I have not any experience with macros, but I belive that is working :)